# How to break and start from where I ended in a nested loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I want  to run this loop over a list basically it searches for a number in my a range till it finds it search for the next number in the following iterations but instead it starts over again

This is my code

```
z = [30,84,126,135,137,179,242,342,426]
c=[]
for m in z:
    for i in range(1,1002, 7):
        if m  in range(i, i+7):
            c.append(m%7)
            break
        elif m not in range(i, i+7):
            c.append(0)
print len(c) # outputs 246
```

but len(c) should be equal to 143, how do I fix this?

Comment: Then why do you `break`?

Comment: because it continues to search for the number in the following ranges even after it finds it and in that case len(c) becomes 1287

Comment: the easiest way is to extract the inner for loop to a method. then the loops don't nest and there is no confusion as to which loop you are breaking

Comment: I don't get it if it breaks and starts over why it doesn't start from where I ended could you illustrate more please !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while a `generator` seemed to answer the question, there is a better tool for the programming problem: `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby


z = [1,2,3, 30,84,126,135,136,137,140,141,179,242,342,426]

g = dict([[k, [*g]] for k, g in groupby(z, key=lambda x: (x-1)//7)])

d = [((tuple(g[i]) if len(g[i]) > 1 else g[i][0]) if (i in g) else 0)
     for i in range(0, 143)]
```

ran against my 1st answer's code: (do use the same `z`, it has been changed)

```
c == d
Out[278]: True
```

see how well matched `itertools.groupby` is look at the dict wrapped groupby result:

```
g
Out[279]: 
{0: [1, 2, 3],
 4: [30],
 11: [84],
 17: [126],
 19: [135, 136, 137, 140],
 20: [141],
 25: [179],
 34: [242],
 48: [342],
 60: [426]}
```

(the above works in 3.6, the `[*g]` and `dictionary key` test `(i in g)` may be different in 2.7)

Comment: Thanks that is really brilliant and more efficient

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out what you're trying to do, and your best bet is to change how you're incrementing your search range.

```
z = [30,84,126,135,137,179,242,342,426]
c=[] # initialize results array
i = 1 # initialize i
for m in z: # for each item in list
    while 1: # perform this action until loop breaks
        if m in range(i, i+7): #if m is in range
            c.append(m%7)
            break #break the while loop, moving on to the next item
        elif m not in range(i, i+7):
            c.append(0) 
            i = i+7 #increment the search range, but do not break the loop

#Display results
print len(c)
print c
```

So in your original code, you reset the search range `i` for each element in the array `z`. This is why your `len(c)` values are getting so much higher than expected. In my code, I only iterate i from 1 to 1002 a single time as I go through the array of values.

Please let me know if this doesn't solve your issue, I was able to match the functionality you described but not the expected output for `len(c)`. If you want to get the expected value, you can change the code to match this:

```
z = [30,84,126,135,137,179,242,342,426]
c=[] # initialize results array
i = 1 # initialize i
for m in z: # for each item in list
    while i<1002: # perform this action until loop breaks
        if m in range(i, i+7): #if m is in range
            c.append(m%7)
            i = i+7
            break # break the while loop, moving on to the next item
        elif m in range(i-7, i):
            break
        else:
            c.append(0) 
            i = i+7 # increment the search range, but do not break the loop

while i<1002: # finish iterating i all the way up to 1002
    c.append(0) 
    i = i+7


#Display results
print len(c)
print c
```

Which gets a `len(c)` of 143.

Comment: Thanks a lot but not my desired output len(c) should equal 143 again there seems to be something wrong with the number of zeros in the list any idea what else I could try ?

Comment: the first solution is better but it stops after the final number in the list how do I make it continue till 1002 which is the end of my ranges

Comment: again it's wrong the first solution where len(c) was 69 was the closest but it needed to continue to 1002 

this one gets most values wrong 

look how c is 


[0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: The first solution stops once the list of values to search for has been exhausted, the second one is the one that gets len(c) to 143.

Comment: but the values are wrong 179, 242, 342 their output should be 4, 4, 6 and it's not in the list

Comment: len(c) = 69
c = [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6]

This is the output of the first solution before you edited it, it's the right solution, it just stops when it reaches the final number in the list I want it to continue to the end 1002

Comment: Spotted the problem, fixed second solution. Should be the right one for sure this time.

Comment: perfect thanks a lot

one final question any idea how I could merge the numbers that fall in the same range like 135,137 into a tuple inside my list ? How do I handle that in the loop ?

Answer (score 1):

perhaps what you want is a `generator` https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions

```
z = [30,84,126,135,136,137,179,242,342,426]
c = []


def counter(maximum, inc):  # resetable generator from doc example
    i = 1
    while i < maximum:
        val = (yield i)
        # If value provided, change counter
        if val is not None:
            i = val
        else:
            i += inc


ig = counter(1002, 7)

for m in z:
    for i in ig:
        # catch multiple nums in same range
        if m < i:
            clast = c.pop()
            # inline if-else inside append converts int to tuple to add m to
            c.append((clast if type(clast) == tuple else (clast,)) + (m,))
            # reset ig count
            ig.send(i - 7)
            break

        if i <= m < i+7:
            c.append(m)
            break
        else:
            c.append(0)
# exhaust ig if you really want full count = 143
for i in ig:
    c.append(0)

print(len(c))
```

added catching nums in same interval, needed the resettable generator

fixed up the last 2 issues I know of:
now makes a flat tuple for multiple nums in a single range
counts correctly by resetting ig to i - 7

Comment: the output is wrong it appends no numbers after 135, so the list is filled with zeros after that, maybe because 137 is in the same range with 135 how do I handle that maybe put the number which fall in the same range in a tuple inside the list